# MYSQL Subrequest too long

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have a very simple subquery, but I think I'm missing something, because MySQL runs it forever.
Let's say I have two tables, a `FruitGenre` and a `FruitFlavor`

```
 FRUIT GENRE
 | id |  name  |
 |  1 |  apple |
 |  2 | orange |

 FRUIT FLAVOR
 | fruit_id | flavor |
 |    1     | cherry |
 |    2     | orange |
```

Yeah, you can have Cherry flavored apples. But any flavor is linked to only one fruit (there cannot be a Cherry flavoured Cherry for example).

My request is as follows:

`SELECT * FROM FruitGenre WHERE id IN (SELECT fruit_id FROM FruitFlavor where FruitFlavor.flavor='cherry')`

However, I can wait an hour and still get no respose. But if I split the request in two, I get immediate responses.

Spliited:

`SELECT fruit_id FROM FruitFlavor where FruitFlavor.flavor='cherry';`

`SELECT * FROM FruitGenre WHERE id IN (id_written_on_paper_from_previous_request)`

Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: *But if I split the request in two* Can you add that code ?

Comment: Did you try this using `EXISTS` or `JOIN` ?

Comment: How many rows you have ih the two tables?

Comment: I did not try a JOIN, the first one (FruitGenre) has 7000 els, and FruitFlavor has 210 000.

Comment: @Prdp yes, done :)

Comment: Can you try your query on a smaller table to check if there's some problem with query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try :

```
SELECT FG.* FROM FruitGenre FG
left join FruitFlavor FF
on FF.id = FG.id
where FF.flavor='cherry'
```

And If you add index in FF.flavo. the query will be faster

Comment: @Prdp, You're right, he can just change left join by inner join to get only row that exist in both tables

Comment: Any how the `Where` clause you used will convert the query to `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM FruitGenre FG 
WHERE Exists (SELECT fruit_id 
              FROM FruitFlavor FF 
              where FG.id = FF.fruit_id 
                AND FF.FruitFlavor.flavor='cherry')
```

Another way using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT FG.id, 
       FG.NAME 
FROM   fruitgenre FG 
       INNER JOIN fruitflavor FF 
               ON FF.id = FG.id 
WHERE  FF.flavor = 'cherry'
```

**Note  :**

- If you don't have any Index on `ID` column of `FRUITGENRE` table then
  create a Non Clustered Index on it
- If you don't have any Index on `Name` column of `fruitflavor` table
  then create a Non Clustered Index on it (Much needed Index considering your query and table size )